# Why this anchor image doesnt work?

Tags: html, css

I just put an image as an anchor, and I honestly don't understand why it doesn't work: anchor does nothing no highlights, and anything. Here's the code of the main section (anchor is under the class name of "exit"):

```
<section id="main">
            <main class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    </div> 

                    <div class="col-xs-5 middle-main">

                     <a href="#" class="exit"></a>

                        <article class="article">

                        </article>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-3 middle-right">
                        <aside>


                        </aside>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </section>

        <div class="container-fluid" id="footer">
        </div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
a.exit  {
    background-image: url(img/exit.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
    float:right;
    opacity:0.8;

}

a.exit:hover {
    opacity:1;

}
```

Why is that?

**UPDATE:**
Ok, i applied the solution that you gave me and it did not quite work, so I will elaborate:

When i put that anchor anywhere OUTSIDE the "middle-main" div container it works, hovers and its clickable, but when i put it inside, the place does not matter, it stops working.

Here's the CSS for classes "middle-main" and the "article" :

```
.middle-main {
    display:none;
    max-width: 600px;
    min-width:300px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:30px;
    background-color: rgba(0,127,92, 0.4); /*0.4 #007F5C;*/
    padding: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
    z-index:-1;

}

.article {
    background-color: rgba(225,255,255, 1); /*0.8 #E1D4D4;*/
    background-image: ;
    color:black;
    padding: 5px  30px 25px 30px;
    }


.article h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

So, "middle-main" is by default display none as it appears in form of FadeIn after i call it through jQuery.

Comment: add display:inline-block; to your css.

Answer (score 2):

In **a.exit** in **css** change `background-image: url(img/exit.svg);` to `background-image: url('img/exit.svg');`

i.e use **''** in url.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `display: block;` to `.exit`

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because `<a>` is inline element and as you don't have any content, it won't show anything.

**You need to change the CSS and first make it `display` as a `block` or inline-block element and define the size.**

**see my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/N86gN/**

```
a.exit  {
  display:block;
  background-image: url(img/exit.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:16px;
  width:16px;
  float:right;
  opacity:0.8;

}

a.exit:hover {
    opacity:1;

}
```

Comment: Still does not want to work.. I updated my post, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the a-tag display:block, otherwise it's inline!

```
a.exit  {
    background-image: url(img/exit.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
    float:right;
    opacity:0.8;
    display:block;
}
```